# Why does Code::Blocks show multiple definition of error?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, definition

I'm using the code [here](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson36/index.php) and I want all the  functions which call SDL functions to be in a different header file instead of the main .cpp file. So I created a new file called Methods.h.
Here is what the files look like:

```
main.cpp:

#include "Methods.h"
...

Methods.h:

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_opengl.h"
....
```

And I removed all the functions from main and put them in Methods.h

When I try to build the project, it says "multiple definition error".

```
/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|29|multiple definition of `event'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|29|first defined here|
obj/Debug/src/Machine.o||In function `drawFrame()':|
/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|29|multiple definition of `drawFrame()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|29|first defined here|
obj/Debug/src/Machine.o||In function `init_GL()':|
/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|73|multiple definition of `init_GL()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|73|first defined here|
obj/Debug/src/Machine.o||In function `init()':|
/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|97|multiple definition of `init()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|97|first defined here|
obj/Debug/src/Machine.o||In function `clean_up()':|
/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|123|multiple definition of `clean_up()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/media/Data1/Projects/OpenGL/Game2/Methods.h|123|first defined here|
```

Comment: Where is include guards? `#ifndef METHODS_H_ #define METHODS_H_ ... #endif`

Comment: Thanks. I put them. Didn't solve it though. Is a there a need in my case actually?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem but it strongly recommended to use include guards in include files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some function definitions in your header file, this means that you'll get a separate definition of each function from each source file that includes the header. They need to be declared `inline` in order to allow them to be defined in every translation unit that includes the header:

```
// Methods.h
#ifndef METHODS_H
#define METHODS_H

inline void initGL() {
    // do stuff
}

#endif
```

Alternatively, you could just declare them in the header, and move the definitions to a source file:

```
// Methods.h
#ifndef METHODS_H
#define METHODS_H

void initGL();

#endif

// Methods.cpp
#include "Methods.h"

void initGL() {
    // do stuff
}
```

There's also a global variable. If you want to keep that, you'll have to move the definition into a source file, and declare it `extern` in the header file. Alternatively, you could replace it with a function that accesses a static variable:

```
inline SDL_Event & event() {
    static SDL_Event instance;
    return instance;
}
```

This has the advantage, and the disadvantage, that it's initialised the first time the function is called.

Comment: THank you
There is a `SDL_Event event;` in  Methods.h .
I intend it to be a global variable. Now I can't put "inline" to this ,can I?

Comment: @learner: No, you can't `inline` that. I've updated my answer with the options.

Comment: Okay, but why does it give a multiple definition error? Where is the multiple definition?

Comment: If the header contains definitions, and you include it from multiple source files, then you'll get multiple definitions - one from each source file that includes it. `inline` relaxes the rules, allowing multiple definitions of a function as long as they're all identical.

Comment: But I haven't included my header in multiple source files. It's only in main.cpp

Comment: According to the error messages, you're also including it from `Machine.cpp` (or from another header included from there).

Comment: I have many const ints declared in my Methods.h . Strangely no issues were raised about them.

Comment: @learner: If they're `const`, then they have internal linkage (as if they were also declared `static`), so you're allowed multiple definitions.

Answer (score 3):

When you add a file in codeblocks using file-new-file-source file etc there is a screen which asks you if you want to include the file in debug and release versions.  If you tick the boxes thinking that of course I want to include them, why else would i be adding the file?  then codeblocks automatically includes your file.  When you then explicity include the file in your code you are duplicating  what it is automatically doing.  So, when adding a file do not tick those boxes because the result is very confusing.  Had this today.

cheers

podge